# Snaplogic REST POST Timeout Error

Tags: json, rest, http-post, snaplogic

I am always facing this error while executing a REST POST. I have even set the Timeout as 100000 but it still fails. Please help me resolve this.

[image]

```
Failure: Failed to execute HTTP request, Reason: connect timed out, Resolution: Please check the Snap properties.
```

Comment: Have you checked the API and tried running it using postman or curl?

Comment: try to check the connectivity between the GroundPlex(if using that) and the endpoint you are trying to connect. You may try using curl or wget commands

Answer (score 0):

Steps to debug this :

1. Make sure the url being used is correct.
2. Make sure the snaplex/groundplex where this request is being executed, that server can access this url. (Try curl to check)
3. If unable to connect, check for firewall/other policies which maybe blocking your request